# How to install the nvm for node.js on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, node.js, nvm

I try to install the `nvm` for my `node.js`. But I have to do `export PYTHON=python2`.

What is this and how does it work?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtualbox. I can't get the nvm installed...  more than two days this is keeping me awake... what did I do wrong?

Comment: You runned the command `wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh` in the Terminal? I did this here and all works fine..(without something as your command..)

Comment: `export PYTHON=python2` would go on a new line in a file such as `~/.bashrc` (you can create the file if it doesn't already exist).  This may or may not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do `export PYTHON=python2` only if python3 is set by default on your system.

First check the python version by running

```
> python --version
> Python 2.7.3
```

If it shows 3.x.x then you should simply run this in this console before running installer eg.

```
export PYTHON=python2
```

then run installer

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
#or
wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
```

See nvm docs [link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#problems).